# Django Reduce Page SQL Queries (Code Optimization)

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, optimization, django-queryset

I have 2 pages that are getting slower and slower one of which is totally unusable when there are more than 10 objects or so involved. I know what the issue is after using the django-debug-toolbar package.

```
ListView page: 23971.48 ms (182 queries including 180 similar and 178 duplicates )
```

I'm fairly new to making optimized database queries and so far everything just works. However, as I said before if I have more than 10 objects (in this case documented trades) things start crashing. I believe a big solution would be to calculate these stats and then save them as fields. Is that the right approach, not at all, or just scratching the surface?

**models.py** (you can tell there are a lot more functions that call many more functions)

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    ...

    # P/L Value = Sum of all buys * ( Entry Cost Per Unit (CPU) - Exit Cost Per Unit (CPU) )
    def get_profit_loss_value_or_None(self):
        if self.get_exit_cpu() > 0:
            if self.type == 'Long':
                result = self.get_entries().aggregate(
                get_profit_loss_value=Sum('amount', output_field=models.FloatField()
                                               ) * (self.get_exit_cpu() - self.get_entry_cpu()))['get_profit_loss_value']
                return 0 if result is None else result
            elif self.type == 'Short':
                result = self.get_entries().aggregate(
                get_profit_loss_value=Sum('amount', output_field=models.FloatField()
                                               ) * -1 * (self.get_exit_cpu() - self.get_entry_cpu()))['get_profit_loss_value']
                return 0 if result is None else result
        else:
            return 0

    #Fight unexpected None errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60576545/nonetype-and-float-error-how-to-avoid-nonetype/60576597?noredirect=1#comment107169241_60576597
    def get_profit_loss_value(self):
        ret = self.get_profit_loss_value_or_None()
        return 0 if ret is None else ret


    # profit_loss_value_fees = profit_loss_value - fees
    def get_profit_loss_value_fees(self):
        result = self.get_profit_loss_value() - self.get_fees()
        return result
```

**views.py**

```
class TradeListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Trade

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('created')
```

**trade_list.html**

```
<!-- Content Row -->

<div class="row">
    {% for trade in object_list reversed %}
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm">
            {% if trade.image %}
            <a href="{{ trade.image.url }}" target="_blank"><img src="{{ trade.image.url }}" class="img-fluid card-img-top" alt="Responsive image"></a>
            {% else %}
            <a target="_blank"><img src="https://tradejournal.s3.amazonaws.com/media/no-image-available-icon.jpg" class="img-fluid card-img-top" alt="Responsive image"></a>
            {% endif %}

            <div class="card-body">
                <h4>
                    <a href="{% url 'trade-detail' trade.id %}" class="card-title card-link">
                        {% if trade.status == "cl" %}
                            {% if trade.get_profit_loss_value_fees > 0 %}
                            <font color="green">${{ trade.get_profit_loss_value_fees|floatformat:2 }}</font>
                            {% elif trade.get_profit_loss_value_fees == 0 %}
                            <font color="#5a5c69">${{ trade.get_profit_loss_value_fees|floatformat:2 }}</font>
                            {% elif trade.get_profit_loss_value_fees < 0 %}
                            <font color="red">${{ trade.get_profit_loss_value_fees|floatformat:2 }}</font>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% else %}
                        <font color="orange">{{  trade.get_status_display }}</font>
                        {% endif %}
                    </a>
                </h4>
                <p>
                    <a href="{% url 'trade-detail' trade.id %}" class="card-text card-link">
                        {{ trade.asset }} | {{ trade.symbol | upper }} | {{ trade.type }}
                    </a>
                </p>
                <p class="card-text">
                    <small>
                        <a href=" {% url 'trade-detail' trade.id %} " class="card-link text-muted"><i class="fas fa-binoculars"></i> View</a>
                        {% if user.is_authenticated and trade.user == user %}
                        <a href=" {% url 'trade-update' trade.id %} " class="card-link text-muted"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>
                        <a href=" {% url 'trade-delete' trade.id %} " class="card-link text-muted"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </small>
                </p>   
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    {% empty %}
    <p class="lead">No trades yet</p>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

---

**Little side thought:**

I've been thinking about making part of this project Open Source as I've been getting a lot of help from the community. It could help future coders in the same place and help to post future questions with more detail. Any thoughts on this? Especially on going about it the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering what I have done so far is to save the calculations as fields and update these "autofields" every time a trade is edited. I have also ran a script to update all existing trades.

models.py (inside the Trade class)

```
#AUTOMATED FIELDS
WIN = 'win'
LOSS = 'loss'
SCRATCH = 'scratch'

RESULT_CHOICES = [
    (WIN, 'win'),
    (LOSS, 'loss'),
    (SCRATCH, 'scratch'),
]
max_amount = models.FloatField(null=True)
fees = models.FloatField(null=True)
entry_cpu = models.FloatField(null=True)
exit_cpu = models.FloatField(null=True)
position_size = models.FloatField(null=True)
profit_loss_percent = models.FloatField(null=True)
profit_loss_value = models.FloatField(null=True)
profit_loss_value_fees = models.FloatField(null=True)
trade_result = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=RESULT_CHOICES, null=True)

def save(self):
    self.max_amount = self.get_max_amount()
    self.fees = self.get_fees()
    self.entry_cpu = self.get_entry_cpu()
    self.exit_cpu = self.get_exit_cpu()
    self.position_size = self.get_position_size()
    self.profit_loss_percent = self.get_profit_loss_percent()
    self.profit_loss_value = self.get_profit_loss_value()
    self.profit_loss_value_fees = self.get_profit_loss_value_fees()
    self.trade_result = self.get_trade_result()
    if not self.id:
        self.created = timezone.now()
    self.modified = timezone.now()
    return super(Trade, self).save()
```